# How do I grep a decimal number from many numbers in a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have string1 of this pattern. `apple:car-cat-3.1.1.1: going to  2.2 home`. 
I want to grep a decimal number. In this string it would be `2.2`.

I tried using `re.search(r'\d+\.\d+',string1)`, when I do this I get `3.1` instead of `2.2`. I search it for a loop of strings, where some strings only have one decimal number and others have more than 1 number with this pattern.

`re.search(r'\d+\.\d+',string1)`

when I do this I get `3.1` instead of `2.2`

Comment: You get 3 matches and [re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=search#re.search) returns the first match it finds. Try matching the number like this `(?<!\S)\d+\.\d+(?!\S)`

Comment: using re.search only?

Comment: You could use search like this https://ideone.com/5CKOgo

Comment: Or `re.search(r'(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)\d+\.\d+(?!\.?\d)',string1)` in a general case will work (even if the digits are glued to some other word chars)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks!! This worked like a charm for other strings

Comment: Also another question, with all these how do I only get last decimal integer. I mean what if a string has " bla bla bla 2.2 (3.4,5.6) and I need only "5.6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=search#re.search) which returns the first match but your regex has [3 matches](https://regex101.com/r/vCfck1/1): `3.1`, `1.1` and `2.2`

If you want to match your value you might use negative lookarounds to check what is on the left and on the right is not a no non-whitespace character:

```
(?<!\S)\d+\.\d+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7B5SxT/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5CKOgo)

For example:

```
import re

string1 = "apple:car-cat-3.1.1.1: going to  2.2 home"
print(re.search(r'(?<!\S)\d+\.\d+(?!\S)',string1).group())
# 2.2
```

Comment: Also another question, with all these how do I only get last decimal integer. I mean what if a string has " bla bla bla 2.2 (3.4,5.6) and I need only "5.6"

Comment: One way could be to use a negative lookahead `\d+\.\d+(?!.*\d+\.\d+)`  https://regex101.com/r/p5fX5b/1